# Unit Testing Scala Future Blocking Contexts

Tags: scala, unit-testing, promise, future

I have a bit of code that reads like this:

```
def someFunctioThatIWantToUnitTest() {
  val p = Promise[Int]()

  val result = getFutureInt(p)
  val resultFut = result.future

  // I extract the content in the resultFut and do what I want
  val didSomething = resultFut.get // not able to get here with my unit test
}
```

The getFutureInt(...) looks like this:

```
private def getFutureInt(promise: Promise[Int]) {
  blocking { // from the scala concurrent object
    // here I successfully return the promise with an Int value
    promise.success(2)
  }
}
```

Assuming that there are proper ExecutionContexts available, I would like to test someFunctioThatIWantToUnitTest method! When I tried to debug my unit test, it would not allow me to get into the blocking block and my test returns with a failure. Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would `scala.concurrent.Await.result` solve your problem?

```
val myFuture = Future(1)
val result: Int = Await.result(myFuture, 1.minute)
```

Keep also in mind that if your test fails early because of `Future.get` invocation, you may never catch any "Future" breakpoint. This is because a test may stop sooner than you expect, destroying all execution contexts by the way. (I don't know the internals to say 100%.)